# Creating an Elastic Image Button Collection

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to create a selection list that is horizontal on non-mobile and vertical on mobile. I have two images of what I'm trying to do:

Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Non-Mobile:

[image: Non-Mobile]

The html for this is, I think, fairly trivial:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <h4>Radio Buttons</h4>
   <div class="elasticradio">
      <div class="elasticradio-default">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
         <label for="radio1">First</label>
      </div>
      <div class="elasticradio-primary">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" checked/>
         <label for="radio2">Second</label>
      </div>
      <div class="elasticradio-success">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
         <label for="radio3">Third</label>
      </div>
      <div class="elasticradio-danger">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
         <label for="radio4">Fourth</label>
      </div>
      <div class="elasticradio-warning">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
         <label for="radio5">Fifth</label>
      </div>
      <div class="elasticradio-info">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
         <label for="radio6">Sixth</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm having difficulty getting the orientation to change. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite as "trivial" as you probably imagined but it can be done with native Bootstrap classes alone i.e. without any custom css.

Here's my take on it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-row mt-4">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="checkbox" id="stocks">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="stocks">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/130/" alt="stocks" class="img-thumbnail d-md-none">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/222/" alt="stocks" class="img-thumbnail d-none d-md-block">
                        <span class="ml-3 ml-md-0">stocks</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="checkbox" id="currencies">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="currencies">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/130/" alt="stocks" class="img-thumbnail d-md-none">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/222/" alt="currencies" class="img-thumbnail d-none d-md-block">
                        <span class="ml-3 ml-md-0">currencies</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="checkbox" id="commodities">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="commodities">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/130/" alt="stocks" class="img-thumbnail d-md-none">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/222/" alt="commodities" class="img-thumbnail d-none d-md-block">
                        <span class="ml-3 ml-md-0">commodities</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="checkbox" id="indices">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="indices">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/130/" alt="stocks" class="img-thumbnail d-md-none">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/222/" alt="indices" class="img-thumbnail d-none d-md-block">
                        <span class="ml-3 ml-md-0">indices</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note: The checkboxes are hidden with the `d-none` class but they should work just fine. So, clicking either the image or the text label will check and uncheck the checkbox.

With a little bit of custom css you could then apply some overlay or effect/animation to the images when the corresponding checkbox is checked.